# cPanel changes are not reflecting

Tags: web, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

I am trying to revamp a website. The host uses `cPanel` as control panel.

I changed something in `index.htm` file but still the old version of website gets loaded.

Just to check, I created another html file `index1.htm`. When I pinged the `<domain-name>/index1.htm`, I got the right page loaded.

What possibly is going wrong here? Is there caching happening, if yes, how can i remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, May be Memcached modules in installed on your server and due to that your are getting this issues, If you want to clear that cache, You will have to access your server through SSH and try with following command.

```
telnet localhost 11211
flush_all
quit
```

Comment: I am not able to connect via `telnet`. Can I somehow clear the cache from `cPanel` like from its file manager.

Comment: First you will check which cache modules you are using on your server. Please contact your hosting provider and ask them to check.